# Quick Scoping technique in Modern Warfare 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

What is the technique to quick-scoping/ no-scoping in MW2?  I understand that there is aim-assist where your crosshair sticks to the enemy, but is that the key to doing it or is there something else I'm unaware of?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to your question, but the perk Slight of Hand, once it hits pro, increases the speed at which you bring up your scope.

Answer (score 8):

- Sleight of Hand Pro
- Stopping Power
- Steady Aim
- Intervention, FMJ

Practice with a throwing knife if you want, but you need to try and get the character in the middle of your screen and tap the sight and fire at almost the same time.  You should not even really see through the scope at any time, though that's up to you to decide what works best.

Also consider carrying akimbo pistols (not G18s) in this class.

Answer (score 1):

**No-scoping (Snipers) is close to impossible in MW2**. Even shooting at point blank at someone is likely to miss. Avoid No-scoping.

As Tzenes says the key to quick-scoping is **Slight of Hand Pro**, apart from that it all comes down to your reflexes. The aim assist in MW2 is so slight that it is close to useless especially if you are quick-scoping.

Comment: sleight not slight, though they're both pronounced the same way.  :D

Comment: Does aim assist even occur in multi-player?

Comment: @stsquad Not in the same fashion. You will not 'pop' to the closest enemy when focusing down the barrel. However, I have noticed you will temporarily 'track' a player if they are at a certain range from you. This is a fleeting response and its mostly just to ensure your aim is focused. I believe is the games' version of a real life peripheral vision.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already spoken to the perks / setup to use, but I'll add a bit on the ideas behind why this can work.

In the call of duty games (at least on xbox 360), there is a mild amount of "aim stick" on enemies. You can see a good demonstration of this by firing up a local match and trying to sweep your aim from the far left of an enemy to the far right. Your sights will slow down while passing over their model.

This affect is amplified when bringing up your sights (ever notice how you aren't quite lined up on someone, then raise your sights and your aim improves?). You can trick the auto aim system to help you by using this aim stick affect to swing your sights closer to the target. It works quite well with shotguns, just try running around with a spas and tapping the left trigger a second before the right. Your sights will jump up before you fire, and if you did it right, the auto-aim system will start to stick to your target for the moment you shoot.

Answer (score 0):

Best load out for quick scoping would be:

Perks

Sleight of Hand (Pro), Steady Aim, Stopping Power

Weapon

Intervention FMJ as your primary and for secondary 44. Magnum Akimbo.

That's my sniping load out and it works when I quick scope.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your technique for quick scoping?